# how can I submit my own ros package to github

Tags: ros, catkin-make, github, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know it would be  a silly question.

Here is the thing. I have my own ros package in Ubuntu running on VMware on windows, and now  I want to run this package on Ubuntu, which is another system of my pc.

I think it should be pretty convenient for me to **submit this package to github on VMware, and then turn to Ubuntu system, clone it and catkin_make from github.**

Is there any **guidline** and any details should be taken care of? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251534/how-can-i-submit-my-own-ros-package-to-github/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is really a github question, not specific to ROS.

Just [create a github repository](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/) in the normal way. Then you can use it for ROS packages or anything else you want.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2